# "TeX-insert-quote" does not work anymore

Tags: latex

Emacs "suddenly" stopped automatically inserting the correct quotes once I hit the <kbd>"</kbd> key. It seems to me that this is due to a duplicate installation of some package, but I can't put my finger on it.

There are some commands that seem to duplicates, so far I stumbled over the following:

```
latex-mode
LaTeX-mode
tex-insert-quote
TeX-insert-quote (")
tex-insert-braces
TeX-insert-braces (C-C {)
```

Sadly, even though helm tells me that `TeX-insert-quote` is bound to `"`, it does not seem to trigger. And even if I call it manually, it simply inserts `"` into my text instead of ``correct'' quotes.

Can anybody point me out where to start diagnosing this behaviour?

Edit: After running `C-h k "` emacs tells me that it's indeed bound to `TeX-insert-quote`. So the trouble is not the binding, but something else.

Comment: Ask Emacs what command is bound to `"` with `C-h k "`.  Start your Emacs without your init file (`emacs -Q`).  Then, recursively bisect your init file (comment out components) until you find out what's causing the conflict.

Comment: Thanks, that allowed me to verify my bindings are correct.

Comment: have you managed to fix this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Sorry, I haven't made any progress on this issue. Currently I am inserting the correct quotes like a caveman :(

Comment: @MatíasGuzmánNaranjo I just found out that my expectation was simply wrong, maybe that is the case for you as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the behaviour of `TeX-insert-quote` has changed from what I was used to. If I simply hit <kbd>"</kbd> **twice** the correct quotation characters are inserted. It used to insert `` "` `` or `"'` immediately, but now does so after the second stroke.

Comment: Do you load babel package with a particular language option? The behavior depends on it, nothing changed in the last years.

Comment: Wow, that might be the root cause: This indeed only happens with german documents. And the more I think about it ... Around the time I asked the question I got around writing german documents in LaTeX for more or less the first time.